# Assisted manual inspection of log files

Tags: debugging, logging, log-analysis

Rookie question here. I've been inspecting a lot of log files to try to pinpoint errors in an application. Specifically I'm trying to compare success scenarios with failure scenarios... but due to the volume of logs it's difficult to identify which log messages are "good" and which ones are "bad". (I'm not the developer, so I can't just change the logs.)

Ideally I'd love a tool where I could...

1. Load a log file and manually specify which entries are associated with a success scenario
2. The rest of the logfile would then be formatted according to whether a given line appears in the "success" scenario or not. (Ideally it could do fuzzy matching, so an exact match (sans timestamp, of course) could be one color and a close match (different value) could be another.

This would make it easy to skim through the failure scenarios and identify messages associated with the failure condition. Think of it like a smart diff.

Most of the tools I've looked at (e.g., Splunk, OtrosLogViewer) seem to be focused on automated server-side deployments. While that could work, I'd love something lighter weight for quick analysis.

Does anything like this exist? Any pointers welcome/appreciated.

Comment: OtrosLogViewer is no focused on server-side deployments, it supports reading logs from remote servers using sftp/ftp/smb/http. You can open logs in OtrosLogViewer and use automatic log markings (by regex or java code) to mark successful scenarios with green and failed with red.

Comment: Thanks, taking another look at OtrosLogViewer now.